# Replace a string multiple times using regular expression

Tags: regex, coldfusion, date-format

for example we have date May 12, 2010

```
<cfset may_12_2010 = CreateDate(2010, 5, 12)>
```

using `DateFormat` function, we can use

```
DateFormat(may_12_2010, "mmmm m dddd d yyyy")
```

which will show `May 5 Wednesday 12 2010`

if for some reason I can't use the `DateFormat` function, how we can show the same results (with the same mask) with the above example?

code:

```
<cfset may_12_2010 = CreateDate(2010, 5, 12)>

<cfset mask = "mmmm m dddd d yyyy">

#DateFormat(may_12_2010, mask)#

<cfset d = DateFormat(may_12_2010, "d") />
<cfset dd = DateFormat(may_12_2010, "dd") />
<cfset ddd = DateFormat(may_12_2010, "ddd") />
<cfset dddd = DateFormat(may_12_2010, "dddd") />

<cfset m = DateFormat(may_12_2010, "m") />
<cfset mm = DateFormat(may_12_2010, "mm") />
<cfset mmm = DateFormat(may_12_2010, "mmm") />
<cfset mmmm = DateFormat(may_12_2010, "mmmm") />

<cfset yy = DateFormat(may_12_2010, "yy") />
<cfset yyyy = DateFormat(may_12_2010, "yyyy") />

<cfset stringDate = mask />

<cfset stringDate = REReplaceNoCase(stringDate, "d{4,4}", dddd, "ALL") />
<cfset stringDate = REReplaceNoCase(stringDate, "d{3,3}", ddd, "ALL") />
<cfset stringDate = REReplaceNoCase(stringDate, "d{2,2}", dd, "ALL") />
<cfset stringDate = REReplaceNoCase(stringDate, "d", d, "ALL") />

<cfset stringDate = REReplaceNoCase(stringDate, "m{4,4}", mmmm, "ALL") />
<cfset stringDate = REReplaceNoCase(stringDate, "m{3,3}", mmm, "ALL") />
<cfset stringDate = REReplaceNoCase(stringDate, "m{2,2}", mm, "ALL") />
<cfset stringDate = REReplaceNoCase(stringDate, "m", m, "ALL") />

<cfset stringDate = REReplaceNoCase(stringDate, "y{4,4}", yyyy, "ALL") />
<cfset stringDate = REReplaceNoCase(stringDate, "y{2,2}", yy, "ALL") />

<br>
#stringDate#
```

the code above will show

```
May 5 Wednesday 12 2010
5ay 5 We12nes12ay 12 2010
```

thank you

Comment: What? Why can't you use DateFormat?

Comment: becausce the "date" object is not actually CF date object, so I have to do it. anyway, thanks for your answer :D

Comment: I'd probably still look at creating a CF date object first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, simply make your regexes:

```
<cfset stringDate = REReplaceNoCase(stringDate, "\bdddd\b" , dddd , "ALL") />
<cfset stringDate = REReplaceNoCase(stringDate, "\bddd\b"  , ddd  , "ALL") />
<cfset stringDate = REReplaceNoCase(stringDate, "\bdd\b"   , dd   , "ALL") />
<cfset stringDate = REReplaceNoCase(stringDate, "\bd\b"    , d    , "ALL") />
....
```

Where the `\b` marks the position of a "word boundary" -- which is a change between a word character and non-word character, where a "word character" is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` -- and so prevents the d's in "wednesday" from matching.

But really, just use the DateFormat function properly!

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as why you can't use dateformat.  I have never had dateformat not accept a value, you can even just use a string, it doesn't care.